# Facing issue while creating user in openfire

Tags: java, openfire, keycloak

I have following simple code which works when I don't have dependency

```
AuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new AuthenticationToken("admin", "password");
        RestApiClient restApiClient = new RestApiClient("http://192.168.20.97", 7070, authenticationToken);
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity("dasddasd","dsadsadasd", "", "password");
        restApiClient.createUser(userEntity);


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And when I add above dependency it throws following error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:316)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:462)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.method(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:295)
    at org.igniterealtime.restclient.RestClient.call(RestClient.java:145)
    at org.igniterealtime.restclient.RestClient.post(RestClient.java:91)
    at org.igniterealtime.restclient.RestApiClient.createUser(RestApiClient.java:92)
    at app.Test.main(Test.java:20)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/xml type: org.igniterealtime.restclient.entity.UserEntity
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:40)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:146)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:121)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:390)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:630)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.buildEntity(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:595)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.loadHttpMethod(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:483)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:305)
    ... 7 more
```

I need above dependency for creating user in Keycloak

Answer (score 0):

You probably just have to add the following dependency in order to get a the *jackson* framework integrated. It will marshal/unmarshal JSON and XML automatically.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Update I have found that resteasy-client is causing third party dependency  resteasy-jaxrs getting added which is usefull in Keycloak user creation but causing issue while creating Opefire user

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the issue is XML vs JSON.  If you look at the [source to RestClient](https://github.com/igniterealtime/REST-API-Client/blob/master/src/main/java/org/igniterealtime/restclient/RestClient.java#L147) which is used by RestApiClient it always sends in XML.  Keycloak is always JSON and so it won't be able to talk XML.

It looks like you can set the `Accepts` header by using [RestClientBuilder](https://github.com/igniterealtime/REST-API-Client/blob/master/src/main/java/org/igniterealtime/restclient/RestClient.java#L314) but the `Content-Type` is hard coded.